# How to format slider

Tags: matplotlib

I have a slider:

```
time_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.03])
var_time = Slider(time_ax, 'Time', 0, 100, valinit=10, valfmt='%0.0f')
var_time.on_changed(update)
```

and I want to customize the appearance of this slider:

[image: screenshot]

I can add `axisbg` parameter to `add_axes` function, which will change default white background to assigned color, but that's all I see possible for now.

So, how to change other slider components:

- silder border (default: black)
- default value indicator (default: red)
- slider progress (default: blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider border is just the spines of the `Axes` instance.  The progress bar can be directly accessed for basic customization in the constructor, and the initial status indicator is an attribute of the slider.  I was able to change all of those things:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure()
time_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.03])

# Facecolor and edgecolor control the slider itself
var_time = Slider(time_ax, 'Time', 0, 100, valinit=10, valfmt='%0.0f',
                  facecolor='c', edgecolor='r')

# The vline attribute controls the initial value line
var_time.vline.set_color('blue')

# The spines of the axis control the borders
time_ax.spines['left'].set_color('magenta')
time_ax.spines['right'].set_color('magenta')
time_ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('magenta')
time_ax.spines['top'].set_color('magenta')
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the facecolor of the slider after the slider has been created?

Answer (score 0):

The color of the box you can change when you define the axis of the "ax" box:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5
f0 = 3
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axfreq = plt.axes([0.03, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65], axisbg=axcolor)
axamp = plt.axes([0.08, 0.25, 0.03, 0.65], axisbg=axcolor)
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)
# The vline attribute controls the initial value line
samp.vline.set_color('green')
```